# Odbc dsn-less conection string error IM002

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc

i want to build an app in cpp, my OS win 10. I have downloaded driver from microsoft docs site.

- driver Microsoft odbc for oracle
  The issue is with SQLDriverConnect in connection string
  If i try to use e.g. this string `"driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};uid=name;pwd=passwd;server=//ip:port/aaa",`
  Throws 2 errors 01500 and IM002. the issue is probably with server arg. so tried this string `"DRIVER=Microsoft ODBC for Oracle; UID=name; PWD=passwd;DBQ=(SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip)(PORT=port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=aaa))));",`

First error fixed but there is still second one IM002. From this [microsoft docs][1] i know that error is with Data source name. I do not want to setup DSN in windows, just want app to be portable without setting dsn
What i am doing wrong, i am beginner in the company and never worked with oracle
Thank you

Note: IP is intranet company DB for customers (because of security)
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver is very old and hasn't been supported in a while.  It will be removed from a future version of Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver15 If you're worried about portability, are the machines you're installing the app guaranteed to have the Oracle client installed?  That's usually a much bigger portability deal than a DSN.  I would guess that you'd want to package the Oracle Instant Client with your app https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html

Comment: Well, i already tried to use instant client but i get error ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: Have you verified that the listener is running on the specified machine for the specified service?  That error generally means that the TNS configuration doesn't match the listener setup.

Comment: Well, i am not a databaze admin, so i do not have access to administration. But i tried to use sqldeveloper, which worked without problems